# Is there a better (more safe) way to get the class of the parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava

I want to create a method that returns the class of parameterized type.

Consider an `interface`:

```
private static interface MyInterface<T> {
    void run(T parameter);
}
```

And one implementation:

```
private static class MyInterfaceImplString implements MyInterface<String> {
    @Override
    public void run(String parameter) {     }
}
```

Now, I want to pass `MyInterfaceImplString.class` to a method and this method will return `String.class`.

I am printing things around, and I can see the information be there but I am just unable to get it. Or at least with a safer way.

```
public class TypesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> genericParameter1 = getGenericParamaterType(MyInterfaceImplVoid.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter1); //expect Void here

        Class<?> genericParameter2 = getGenericParamaterType(MyInterfaceImplString.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter2); //expect String here
    }

    private static Class<?> getGenericParamaterType(Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> clazz) {
        for (Method m : clazz.getMethods()) {
            if ("run".equals(m.getName()) && m.getParameterCount() == 1) {
                System.out.println(TypeLiteral.get(clazz).getParameterTypes(m));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static class MyInterfaceImplVoid implements MyInterface<Void> {

        @Override
        public void run(Void parameter) {           }
    }

    private static class MyInterfaceImplString implements MyInterface<String> {

        @Override
        public void run(String parameter) {         }

    }

    private static interface MyInterface<T> {
        void run(T parameter);
    }
}
```

Ignore the `null` return value in the method. I just want to print things, see what I get and then return it. However, my current implementation seems kind of unorthodox because the class might have more than one `run` method that has nothing to do with `MyInterface`.

In case of [a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I want be to able to recognize which of these implementations contain a parameterized type that `extends Employee` (let's say). I call the `run` method of the interface indirectly given an `HourlyPaidEmployee` or a `MonthlyPaidEmployee`. So, if the underlying implementation is `MyInterface<Employee>`, I can inject my actual employee (either is monthly or hourly paid). But if the implementation is `MyInterface<HourlyEmployee>`, I cannot inject a monthly paid one. So, getting the class of the parameterized type, helps me know what types of Employees I can inject safely to `run` method.

I am with java-8 and `Guice` dependency in classpath, which contains `guava` dependency.

**EDIT:** @Glorfindel made good point in his answer. But if the implementation looks like:

```
private static class MyInterfaceImplVoid implements MyInterface<Void> {

    @Override
    public void run(Void parameter) {
    }

    public void run(Integer par) {
    }
}
```

I am not able to know what is the method that refers to the interface, hence his answer might return to me  `Integer.cass`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not deal with methods when you want to find out the actual type arguments of the *type*. You can implement it for the scenario as simple as your using

```java
public class TypesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type genericParameter1 = getGenericParameterType(MyInterfaceImplVoid.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter1+", "+(genericParameter1==Void.class));

        Type genericParameter2 = getGenericParameterType(MyInterfaceImplString.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter2+", "+(genericParameter2==String.class));
    }

    private static Type getGenericParameterType(Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> clazz) {
        for(Type interfaceType: clazz.getGenericInterfaces()) {
            if(interfaceType == clazz)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("raw implementation");
            if(interfaceType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)interfaceType;
                if(pt.getRawType() == MyInterface.class)
                    return pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented directly");
    }
}
```

```
class java.lang.Void, true
class java.lang.String, true
```

But note that the return type is `Type`, not class, as the type argument is not guaranteed to be a `Class` (a reifiable type or a raw type). It could be a parameterized type on its own, but also a type variable.

Consider a case like

```java
abstract class InTheMiddle<T> implements MyInterface<T> {}
class Implementation extends InTheMiddle<String> {
    @Override
    public void run(String parameter) {
    }
}
```

This would be solvable be traversing the type hierarchy, querying the [declared type variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters()) and match them with the actual type arguments when they appear at the target type variable you want to resolve.

But mind that the following also is possible:

```java
abstract class Outer<T> {
    class Inner implements MyInterface<T> {
        @Override
        public void run(T parameter) {
        }
    }
}
class SubclassOfOuter extends Outer<Integer> {
}
```

```java
SubclassOfOuter outer = new SubclassOfOuter();
MyInterface<Integer> object = outer.new Inner();
```

which would require traversing the type hierarchy and the artifacts of the lexical scope (besides outer classes, implementation classes can be local classes of a generic method placed inside a generic class that may be local to another method…).

Then, there are the constructs that are impossible to query at runtime at all, due to type erasure:

```java
class GenericImpl<X> implements MyInterface<X> {
    @Override
    public void run(X parameter) {
    }
}
GenericImpl<String> a = new GenericImpl<>();
GenericImpl<Integer> b = new GenericImpl<>();
```

or

```java
MyInterface<Thread> another = t -> {};
```

So think twice before you make your code dependent on the ability to determine the actual type argument at runtime.

Comment: (1+). Your method covers my needs. Plus, it is java only. (Not to mention my chaotic one). Thanks. And in order to answer your comment in the other answer, I never claimed Guava undoes type erasure. I just thought that Guava is able to find the generic parameterized type somehow while pure java can't. Probably calling natives. I actually reconsidered it though. Since they are erased, it probably won't be capable of doing it. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If I replace

```
System.out.println(TypeLiteral.get(clazz).getParameterTypes(m));
```

with

```
return m.getParameterTypes()[0];
```

I get the following output:

```
class java.lang.Void  
class java.lang.String
```

No need for Guice/Guava, plain old Java seems to work fine. I do not know a good solution for the other problem; it seems reflection isn't even able to detect that one method is an override and the other one is not. If you have sufficient control over the implementation classes, I'd advice simply to use another name instead of `run` for the other method.

Comment: Edited my question. Check it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know of a solution to that case, other than not using potentially clashing method names...

Comment: I have posted an answer that works, in case you are interested. Thank you for time & effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your `T` is unbound.

That means every impl of this interface, even your `MyInterfaceImplVoid`, **will** have a `run(Object)` method, even if you didn't write one at all - and it will cast the argument to in this case `Void` and pass the call onwards to `run(Void)`. So, if you want to be sure you call the interface method, always call `run(Object)`, and send an object of the right type (as figured out via @Glorfindel 's answer).

Note that this 'trick' of figuring out what the bound is usually a bad plan. What are you going to do when I write this class:

```
class DynamicMyInterface<Z> implements MyInterface<Z> {
    private Class<Z> forcedType;

    public DynamicMyInterface(Class<Z> type) {
        this.forcedType = type;
    }

    public void run(Z in) {
        forcedType.cast(in);
        ....
    }
}
```

Your jaunt into `.getGenericType()` and such will **never** be able to figure out what it is, because of erasure. You won't get any further than `Z extends Object`.

Comment: I am aware about the erasure at runtime. That's why I mention, and try to do it with Guava. I am also aware that asking the type works in pure java too. However, asking the type in constructor is not an option for my use case. Thank you for your time. If you are interested, I have posted something below that works.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Guava can not undo type erasure. It does not contain magic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the class of the parameterized type with this "ugly" - "what the heck" method:

```
private static Class<?> getGenericParamaterType(Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> clazz) {
    for (TypeToken<?> typeToken : TypeToken.of(clazz).getTypes()) {
        Class<?> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        if (rawType == MyInterface.class) {
            TypeLiteral<?> typeLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(typeToken.getType());
            for (Method method : rawType.getMethods()) {
                if ("run".equals(method.getName())) {
                    TypeLiteral<?> typeLiteral2 = typeLiteral.getParameterTypes(method).get(0);
                    return typeLiteral2.getRawType();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works exactly as I want. However, I am not sure for its performance. Plus, I really think that Guava provides a more concise way to achieve what I want. In the other hand, I was not able to find it.

Below is the full example that shows that it works. Even in complex situations where multiple `run` methods are implemented by the implementation and even in abstract classes that do not implement the method.

```
public class TypesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> genericParameter1 = getGenericParamaterType(MyInterfaceImplVoid.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter1); //expect Void here

        Class<?> genericParameter2 = getGenericParamaterType(MyInterfaceImplString.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter2); //expect String here

        Class<?> genericParameter3 = getGenericParamaterType(AbstractImpl.class);
        System.out.println(genericParameter3); //expect Integer here
    }

    private static Class<?> getGenericParamaterType(Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> clazz) {
        for (TypeToken<?> typeToken : TypeToken.of(clazz).getTypes()) {
            Class<?> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
            if (rawType == MyInterface.class) {
                TypeLiteral<?> typeLiteral = TypeLiteral.get(typeToken.getType());
                for (Method method : rawType.getMethods()) {
                    if ("run".equals(method.getName())) {
                        TypeLiteral<?> typeLiteral2 = typeLiteral.getParameterTypes(method).get(0);
                        return typeLiteral2.getRawType();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static class MyInterfaceImplVoid extends JPanel implements MyInterface<Void>, Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run(Void parameter) { 
        }

        public void run(Integer par) {          }

        public void run(String s) {         }

        @Override
        public void someOtherMethod() {         }

        @Override
        public void run() {         }

    }

    private static abstract class AbstractImpl implements MyInterface<Integer> {

    }

    private static class MyInterfaceImplString implements MyInterface<String> {

        @Override
        public void run(String parameter) {         }

        @Override
        public void someOtherMethod() {         }

    }

    private static interface MyInterface<T> {
        void run(T parameter);

        void someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

I will not mark this answer as accepted since I am quite sure there is a more convenient way to do it.

Comment: No, this does not work. run it against this one: `class Broken implements MyInterface<Integer> { public void run(String s) {} @Override public void run(Integer i) {}` - this will randomly return Integer or String. Also, your getGenericParamater method does all this TypeToken voodoo and completely ignores it (`typeLiteral` is never returned) - why do all that effort? More generally, 'look for the run method to figure out the type' cannot work. You can look for the run(Object) method to invoke it, though.

Comment: @rzwitserloot No matter what I do, given class `Broken`, I always get `Integer.class` as result. However, I understand that when it comes to reflection, things can be random. About the effort, did you read the XY problem section of my question? I want to be able to know what to inject as a parameter to an implicit call. Is there any other approach I can get?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Also, inside my method, If you `System.out.println(typeToken);` you will get output such `TypesTest$MyInterface<java.lang.Integer>`. This string contains the info I am looking for. Maybe it is better (more safe) to extract it from the string?

Comment: No, it's not safe to extract it from the string. You can get that Integer from the typetoken object.